# Gradle Guides, Building Java Web Application - Gradle build throwing java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, gretty

I'm trying to work through the "Building Java Web Applications" Gradle Guide (kotlin dsl), but gradle throws an exception when building.  I would really appreciate any help getting this guide to work.  I'm using gradle 6.2.2.  I've cloned the gradle / guides & tried building the example there with the same results.

**settings.gradle.kts**

```
rootProject.name = "webdemo"
```

**build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    war
    id("org.gretty") version "2.2.0"
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

gretty {
    integrationTestTask = "test"
}

dependencies {
    providedCompile("javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0")
    testCompile("junit:junit:4.12")
    testCompile("org.mockito:mockito-core:2.7.19")
    testCompile("io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager:1.6.1")
    testCompile("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.3.1")
}
```

**Exception**

```
% ./gradlew build                                                                                                                                                                                                                          (git)-[master] 
Exception in thread "Thread-447" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The configuration :grettyNoSpringBoot was resolved from a thread not managed by Gradle.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveToStateOrLater(DefaultConfiguration.java:565)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1900(DefaultConfiguration.java:141)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getSelectedArtifacts(DefaultConfiguration.java:1246)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.visitContents(DefaultConfiguration.java:1237)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:1226)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:484)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getFiles(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
        at groovy.lang.MetaBeanProperty.getProperty(MetaBeanProperty.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.getProperty(BeanDynamicObject.java:232)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryGetProperty(BeanDynamicObject.java:175)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.tryGetProperty(CompositeDynamicObject.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getProperty(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:298)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.DefaultLauncher.getRunnerClassPath(DefaultLauncher.groovy:33)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:483)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:195)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.ConfigureDelegate.invokeMethod(ConfigureDelegate.java:77)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeOnDelegationObjects(ClosureMetaClass.java:397)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:337)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:64)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:176)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.DefaultLauncher$_javaExec_closure7.doCall(DefaultLauncher.groovy:94)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:263)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:421)
        at org.gradle.util.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:154)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:105)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$WrappedConfigureAction.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:166)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecActionFactory.javaexec(DefaultExecActionFactory.java:144)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.javaexec(DefaultProject.java:1129)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.javaexec(DefaultProject.java:1124)
        at org.gradle.api.Project$javaexec$6.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.DefaultLauncher.javaExec(DefaultLauncher.groovy:93)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:351)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:64)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:168)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.LauncherBase$_launchThread_closure4.doCall(LauncherBase.groovy:259)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.LauncherBase$_launchThread_closure4.doCall(LauncherBase.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:263)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:399)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:486)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
<=========----> 70% EXECUTING [8s]
> :appBeforeIntegrationTest
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't write this as a comment, but your error most likely comes from your wrapper version.

When you type:

```
./gradlew -v
```

what do you get?
If it is the same version as your global gradle, then the error occurs.

Change it for:

```
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=4.10.3
```

as stated in the guide.

Comment: I’m using 6.2.2.  I had just assumed that the guide hadn’t been updated.  So, what your saying is they have a regression problem for Java web apps?

Comment: It looks like it, but I can't say. I stumbled on the same error and fixed it that way. I hope this let's you continue.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same error and found this page while I was looking for a solution. 
The problem went away after I changed the plugin version to the latest.

```
    id 'org.gretty' version '3.0.3'
```

I am on gradle 6.4 and openjdk version 14.

Comment: This makes more sense than messing with the gradle wrapper version if you are using latest or recent versions of gradle.